# How to join every row from table A to every two rows from table B

Tags: mysql, sql

How to join every row from table A to every two rows from table B

I have two table
Table A

| date | league_name | league_id | match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date1 | name1 | 1032 | team1 vs team2 |
| date2 | name2 | 1033 | team3 vs team4 |

Table B

| team_name | goal_for | goal_against | team_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team1 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| team2 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| team3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| team4 | 7 | 3 | 4 | 2 |

To get Result like this

two rows after joining table A and table B

| date | league_name | league_id | match | team_name | g_for | g_against | team_id | status | team_name | goal_for | goal_against | team_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date1 | name1 | 1032 | team1 vs team2 | team1 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 1 | team2 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| date2 | name2 | 1033 | team3 vs team4 | team3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 | team4 | 7 | 3 | 4 | 2 |

note the status column the home team status is 1 and away team column is 2 so i wish to have the the two rows together join a row on the table A

Comment: It is hard to think of a worse data model for this type of data.  Your model will not support a single team having multiple matches.

Comment: dude, i can only making do with what i was given

Answer (score 1):

Test

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TableA t1
JOIN TableB t2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.match, ' ', 1) = t2.team_name
JOIN TableB t3 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.match, ' ', -1) = t3.team_name
```

But I recommend to store teams in separate columns instead of solid `match` column (which may be generated or, as a palliative, overdefined).